# Inefficienies of solid AA mild steel battery

Tags: batteries, resistance

I have an enclosure which has only 32x35 space for 3xAA battery, which will power my device. My device has been build to work on 3AA batteries and lasts for a year on cheap salt batteries.

I am left with 2 options:

1. Merge 2xAA and 1XAA battery holder and make a 3xAA : Won't be as cool looking, but will do the job
2. Use a 4XAA back to back battery holder, and put a dummy AA battery, and block one compartment so end user cannot use it.

I'm inclined towards Option 2 as its less work and better looking. So I contacted foundry workshops to figure out costing of solid mild steel battery, and it was very reasonable at 100 qty (20 cents).

My device though is built for low power usage and lasts a year on 3 salt batteries. I'm interested to know what kind of losses to expect. What resistance would this dummy battery have? Would adding this dummy battery have significant impact on life of my device?

Comment: What are "salt" batteries?  A solid steel dummy AA cell will be heavy and prone to rust and bad connections.

Comment: Salt batteries I guess refers to Carbon zinc batteries, which are super cheap, usually intended for wall clocks.

Comment: Weight not too much at 55gm. Bad connection? I just want to get a clue if they will affect life of my device in terms of losses.. I guess rust is not really that big concern, as long it's under control..

Comment: Also, what if aluminium solid battery is used? Solid AL won't be super costly either, around 30cents per piece

Comment: You can easily look up the bulk resistivity of steel, and work it out yourself.

Comment: Use four AA cells and a voltage regulator.

Comment: What is stopping you getting a battery holder that takes 3 AA cells?

Comment: @jre pcb is ready. The device is meant for 3xaa not 4xaa

Comment: @user, I would appreciate if you can help me figure this out. Assume 14mm dia, 50mm length cylindrical solid mild steel

Comment: 3xaa holder won't fit in dimensions I mentioned in question. I have around 32x35 mm space

Comment: L-shaped holder https://www.batteryholders.com/part.php?pn=BC3AAGW&original=AA&override=AA  made in Taiwan. (not China)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy dummy AA batteries, sold for use in occupying a position when a battery such as a [Sony 14500](https://voltaplex.com/media/whitepapers/specification-sheet/Sony_US14500VR_Specification_Sheet.pdf)  is used to replace alkaline cells- since one 14500 is 3.6V.

Cost in China is quite low, and resistance is low single-digit m\$\Omega\$ so I think you should be able to source them for a reasonable price compared to trying to make them yourself. They will also have significantly less mass. A high-mass dummy cell may lead to problems when your product is subjected to mechanical acceleration or shock (eg. dropped) because of the relatively high mass. A very high quality battery holder will probably be okay, but cheaper ones that use brass and do not have mechanical stops to prevent yield stress from being exceeded may well require the holder to be opened and the coil spring to be stretched out after such an event. Photo below from Amazon.com:

[image]

If you do try to manufacture such an item, you should probably arrange for them to be nickel plated all over to prevent corrosion and bad connections. That can be done with an inexpensive barrel plating process.

---

To answer the specific question posed, the losses will be negligible compared to internal resistance of the batteries and the resistance of the wires and interconnections. The resistivity of carbon steel is about 10x that of copper, but the cross-sectional area of the dummy cell is enormous compared to the typical thin wires or copper traces used in a circuit. Even the 5.5mm button end has a huge cross section.

Comment: I don't want to import from China, if this solution for solid dummy metal works. Besides, all other disadvantages you've suggest don't seem to be of concern for my device

Comment: A humble request, can I get an idea of the impact on life for 3xaa battery, in terms of losses? Or resistance of this thing?

Comment: It will be negligible compared to losses in the wire etc. Carbon steel has about 10x the resistivity of copper, but the cross-sectional area (even of the button top) is enormous.

Comment: So are you saying the resistance of dummy battery will be lower than if I connected a copper wire?

Comment: Any reasonable size of copper wire, yes. Square root of 10 is about 3, so even a steel cylinder the size of the 5.5mm end button has about as much conductance as a ~2.7 mm diameter copper wire. Obviously a solid body will add significantly to that conductance.